# Tensorflow uses GPU's that aren't visible

Tags: python, deep-learning, gpu

I am trying to train a neural network on a subset of the GPU's that I have access to.
The problem is that I want to use only two GPU's so I wrote the following command in the .bashrc:

`export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=6,7`

However, when I watch the gpus, I find that my program is mainly using other GPU's (4,5) with 100% memory utilization and using only the visible gpus with very low memory utilization (9% maximum).

I have already closed and reopened all the terminals to restart the ~/.bashrc but the problem still persists!

Any help is appreciated!

P.S: I already successfully ran the same program before on only two GPUs but on a different server, so the memory is not a constraint here.

Comment: Did you check from the terminal in which you run your script that the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` is set correctly?

Comment: Also maybe the ordering on the machine is different than in CUDA. I need to set CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER to PCI_BUS_ID to get the correct GPUs.

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes I already did that and it showed (6,7)

edit: ok may bad! I was checking the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` from the terminal and not from the tmux session. I closed all the terminals but I forgot the tmux session!